# Meck behaving strangely for multiple mocked modules

Tags: erlang, meck

I have following module

```
-module(bhavcopy_downloader).

-export([download/2]).

download(From, SaveTo) ->
    {ok, {{Status, _}, _, Body}} = lhttpc:request(From, "GET", [], infinity),
    case Status of 
        200 ->  file:write(SaveTo, Body),
            true;
        _ -> false
    end.
```

And following tests for the above code

```
file_download_test_() -> 
    {foreach,
     fun() ->
            meck:new(lhttpc)
            meck:new(file, [unstick])
     end,
     fun(_) ->
        meck:unload(file),
            meck:unload(lhttpc) 
     end,
      {"saves the file at specified location",
        fun() ->
            meck:expect(lhttpc, request, 4, {ok, {{200, "OK"}, [], <<"response">>}}),
            meck:expect(file, write_file, fun(Path, Data) -> 
                                    ?assertEqual(Path, "~/Downloads/data-downloader/test.html"), 
                                    ?assertEqual(Data, <<"response">>) 
                            end),
            ?assertEqual(true, bhavcopy_downloader:download("http://google.com", "~/Downloads/data-downloader/test.html")),
            ?assert(meck:validate(file))
        end}]

    }.
```

When I run the tests I get following error (only part of the error pasted below for brevity). Looking at the error below, I am kind of feeling that file module is not being mocked (or the mock of file module being overridden when I set the other mock using `meck:new(lhttpc)`. What could be going wrong here?

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 16-Feb-2013::20:17:24 ===
** Generic server file_meck terminating 
** Last message in was {'EXIT',<0.110.0>,
                    {compile_forms,
                     {error,
                      [{[],
                        [{none,compile,
                          {crash,beam_asm,
                           {undef,
                            [{file,get_cwd,[],[]},
                             {filename,absname,1,
                              [{file,"filename.erl"},{line,67}]},
                             {compile,beam_asm,1,
                              [{file,"compile.erl"},{line,1245}]},
                             {compile,'-internal_comp/4-anonymous-1-',2,
                              [{file,"compile.erl"},{line,273}]},
                             {compile,fold_comp,3,
                              [{file,"compile.erl"},{line,291}]},
                             {compile,internal_comp,4,
                              [{file,"compile.erl"},{line,275}]},
                             {compile,'-do_compile/2-anonymous-0-',2,
                              [{file,"compile.erl"},{line,152}]}]}}}]}],
                      [{"src/lhttpc_types.hrl",
                        [{31,erl_lint,{new_builtin_type,{boolean,0}}},
                         {31,erl_lint,{renamed_type,bool,boolean}}]}]}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a catch 22 in Meck, caused by the fact that Meck uses the Erlang compiler, which in turns uses the `file` module. When Meck tries recompile the `file` module it needs the `file` module (through the compiler) and thus crashes.

As of this moment, Meck doesn't handle mocking the file module. Your best alternative is to wrap the `file` module calls in another module and mock this module instead.

(*It is theoretically possible to fix this in Meck by using the internals of the compiler and the code server instead, for example [`erlang:load_module/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#load_module-2)*, however this is quite tricky and needs to be designed and tested well)

Comment: At the moment I'm on windows machine and my code is on linux box. I would need to reboot my machine to confirm that this works. But I do have a feeling that this answers my question. I would accept the answer for now and come back to it later.